# Scraper doesn't load all page content

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to scrape the table from a page (you can find it in the code). When I run the code as it is, it always shows me that the "Table not found". I tried to copy the HTML code in as as a variable and run it like that and it works.

What could be the problem? Does the page use JS and I need to use Selenium or Scrapy, or is it something else?

Here is the code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://www.flightradar24.com/data/aircraft/n230wp"

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/119.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/119.0.0.0",
    "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.9,hr;q=0.8"
}


response = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)
content = response.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "lxml")

table = soup.find('table', {'id': 'tbl-datatable'})

# Check if the table is found
if table:
    # Iterate through rows in the table body
    for row in table.select('tbody tr'):
        # Extract data from each column in the row
        columns = row.find_all(['td', 'th'])
        row_data = [col.get_text(strip=True) for col in columns]
        
        # Print row data
        print(row_data)
else:
    print("Table not found.")
```

Comment: use `Selenium` instead, way better to work with

Comment: Your code works if `soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "lxml")` is replaced by `soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "html.parser")`. `html5lib` parser works as well

Comment: @bartolo-otrit Yes it seems the code works when you change it to "html.parser". Thank you.

I had to use Selenium in the end beacuse I had to scroll through the page.

Thank you both for the help.